# How to determine the value of a textbox based on the previous textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I want determine the value of textbox based on the previous textbox using JavaScript, But the code it's not work.

[image: Here the result]

Here the javascript

```js
  function result_method(){
    var bw_method =document.getElementById("bw_method");
    var w_method = document.getElementById("w_method");
    var result_method = document.getElementById("result_method");

    if (!isNaN(bw_method.value="Accepted", w_method.value="Accepted")){
      document.querySelector('[name="result_method"]').value = "Pass";
      }else{
        document.querySelector('[name="result_method"]').value="Fail";
      }

  }
```

```html
         <label> Before Wash </label>
            <select name="bw_method" id="bw_method" class="form-control" onkeyup="result_method();" disabled>
                <option selected >PILIH</option>
                <option value="Accepted">Accepted</option>
                <option value="Rejeceted">Rejected</option>
               </select>
           
     
          <label> 1. wash </label>
           <select name="w_method" id="w_method" class="form-control" onkeyup="result_method();">
             <option selected disabled>PILIH</option>
                 <option value="Accepted">Accepted</option>
             <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
            </select>
   
        <label> Result </label>
          <input name="result_method" id="result_method" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
```

Please help me, thankyouuuu

Comment: In your code, you have two select boxes and 1 result textbox, do you actually mean : if the user has selected **both** select boxes as "Accepted", then the result textbox should show "Pass" (else should show "Fail") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following working demo, there were issues in condition and its passed values,

```js
function result_method() {
    let bw_method =document.getElementById("bw_method");
    let w_method = document.getElementById("w_method");
    let result_method = document.getElementById("result_method");
    let result = (bw_method.value === "Accepted" && w_method.value === "Accepted") ? "Pass" : "Fail";
    document.querySelector('[name="result_method"]').value = result;
}
```

```html
<label> Before Wash </label>
<select name="bw_method" id="bw_method" class="form-control" onchange="result_method();" disabled>
  <option>PILIH</option>
  <option value="Accepted" selected>Accepted</option>
  <option value="Rejeceted">Rejected</option>
 </select>
               
 <label> 1. wash </label>
 <select name="w_method" id="w_method" class="form-control" onchange="result_method();">
   <option selected disabled>PILIH</option>
       <option value="Accepted">Accepted</option>
   <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
  </select>
   
 <label> Result </label>
 <input name="result_method" id="result_method" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your javascript function is if the condition syntax is incorrect try to below.

```
if (bw_method === "Accepted" && w_method === "Accepted") {
     result_method.value = "Pass";
} else { 
     result_method.value = "Fail";
 }
}
```

Try this one